# Disabling tree-shaking in Webpack 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, web-component

How would I disable tree-shaking in Webpack 3?

I am experimenting with building a web app in completely native Web Components, and I am relying on cloning and appending a template element with innerHTML to render any sub-components within it. However, since webpack doesn't see me using the sub-component within the javascript, it doesn't bundle the appropriate file, so the web component is never defined.

```
import MyComponent from './my-component';
let template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
<h1>My Web App</h1>
<my-component></my-component>
`;

export default class WebApp extends HTMLElement {
    constructor () {
        super();
        let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
}
```

If I included a call like `let myComponent = new MyComponent();`, I can see webpack finally bundles the import, so I believe it's because the component is defined in the template string.

Thanks.

Comment: My understanding it that it's not WebPack that's doing this; it's TypeScript. Use an import like this, instead: `import './my-component';` Search for "side-effects only" in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Webpack wasn't the culprit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't Webpack removing the bundle, but the typescript compiler. Typescript would 'elide' the import since it wasn't being used, however changing the import statement from `import MyComponent from './my-component';` to `import './my-component';` forces typescript to include it.

Thanks you @cartant!